# Julia: How can I access a type from inside a module?

Tags: types, module, julia

Suppose that I would like to access, from inside a module, a type on an englobing scope. To be concrete:

file Englobing.jl

```
using myModule
type MyType
    a::Float64
    b::Vector{Float64}
end

t = MyType( 1., [ 1., 2. ] )

x = [ .5, .5 ]

myFunc( x, t )
```

file myModule.jl

```
module myModule

export myFunc

    function myFunc( x::Vector{Float64}, z::MyType )
        [ operations ]
    end

end
```

In this case, I would like to be able to access the type MyType from inside the module myModule, without using `global`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can export types too.  E.g. if `Englobing.jl` were a module, you could have:

```
export MyType
```

Then, within your `myModule.jl` file you could have:

```
using Englobing
```

**Option 2**

If `Englobing.jl` weren't a module (which it isn't currently written as), you could just use

```
include("Englobing.jl")
```

within `MyModule.jl`.

Both of these do depend, however, on not having a situation where `Englobing.jl` uses something (function, type, object, etc.) from `MyModule.jl` while at the same time `MyModule.jl` uses something from `Englobing.jl`.  If the desired outcome is to have a situation like that possible, I do not believe that is achievable in Julia, though I don't quite see why it would be desirable either.

Comment: Thank you - I would normally expect the ability to have a behavior similar to the `extern` in C/C++, i.e. to have a declaration in `myModule.jl` that refers to the type `MyType`, defined elsewhere.

Comment: @Dimitris What about using `include()` in your module to load the separate file that defines the type?  Or, you can use `using` in `MyModule.jl` to load a separate module that defines the type.  Do these get at what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

We try to avoid implicit dependencies, i.e. saying "give me whatever definition of `MyType` might be around". You have to say exactly where it comes from.

However, it is possible for two modules to use each other. `module A` can contain `using B`, and `module B` can contain `using A`. You have to order the statements in each so that one can be loaded during loading of the other, but it can work. Of course this is frowned upon, since two modules that depend on each other are not really separate in a meaningful way.

Another solution is to put one module lexically inside the other. It is possible to import variables from scopes that surround the code for the module itself:

```
module Outer    # or just Main, the default

type MyType
    ...
end

module myModule

import ..MyType   # imports from the outer module

end

using .myModule

end
```

As Michael said, you could then put the code for `myModule` in a separate file, and `include` it in different places to automatically pick up different definitions of `MyType`. However it's preferred to just have a clean dependency tree of modules.